# Object appears smoothed after rendering but not in viewport

Tags: rendering, objects

I'm pretty new to blender and used it to model a castle and print it.
Now I want to extend the model by textures and render it, but even when I render
it with basic material i get some strange output.

Does somebody know my error? I already corrected the normals and they look fine.

[image: Model:]

[image: Render:]

Comment: you are using subsurf modifier with higher settings in the render than in the view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have a subdivision surface modifier (or multiresolution) set to render only, not visible in viewport but active when rendering.

[image]

Click the eye to see it, click the X to remove it.

As suggested by Chebhou, the subsurf modifier can also be different in viewport/render because of the subdivision levels number set for each.

[image]