# Why are there square artifacts in my render?

Tags: rendering, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine

Im working on a new Anime/Toon Material for all of my characters for a short film type thing. The main issue is that when I render I get these squares in the render that I don't see on the preview, or in cycles [image: Problem]. 
I want it too look like this and this is what the render preview look like
[image: Intended Look]

How do I fix this? here's the file 
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42587

The problem seems to be withe the solidify modifier but i need the "line" Effect and don't want to use blender freestyle as I can't get a good preview of the look without constant rendering, witch really messes with my workflow.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for discrepancy are different settings for preview and render of the [Multires](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/multiresolution.html) modifier.

From [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/multiresolution.html#options):

> **Preview**
>       Set the level of subdivisions to show in the 3D View.
>
> **Sculpt**
>       Set the number of subdivisions to use in Sculpt Mode.
>
> **Render**
>       Set the number of subdivisions to show when rendering.

In your file, *Render* option is set to 1, and thus it uses the first level of subdivision when rendering image.

[image: screenshot of different multires settings]

On this level mesh becomes more bumpy and with rough sides, which reflect the light you see on the rendered image.
It is not visible in 3D Viewport because *Preview* is set to 2, which makes mesh smoother only for previewing it in the viewport.

See related answers:

[Object appears smoothed after rendering but not in viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24602/object-appears-smoothed-after-rendering-but-not-in-viewport) - specific case with Multires modifier.

[Cycles viewport render different than f12 render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/985/cycles-viewport-render-different-than-f12-render) - general things to consider when preview and render results differ.

Comment: It looks Better, but im still getting small squares under the arm's. Looks near the left armpit withe the light set to sun or point.

Comment: @Steven I didn't see any real difference between [rendered image](http://i.imgur.com/iSmFyWY.jpg) and [preview render](http://i.imgur.com/cUd76OH.jpg) except for normal differences in antialiasing which is what will differ in any way. You could look at [technical differences between them](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-f12-render-and-viewport-preview)